# Find the number of columns of an array in julia

Tags: syntax, julia

I have been trying to find the number of columns of an array but apparently the `ncols` , `size`, and `length` functions don't produce the desired output.

Any suggestion on what is the correct way to find the number of columns of an array?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To find the number of rows of an array, `X`:

```
size(X, 1)
```

To find the number of columns

```
size(X, 2)
```

For the length of the n'th dimension:

```
size(X, n)
```